# Delphi threadvar question

Tags: multithreading, delphi

When we have a `threadvar` declared, when this variable will be initialized (the object is created)? Does it occurs at the first assignment of the var? For example:

```
threadvar
  myThreadVar : string;

......

//inside a thread
  ...
  myThreadVar := 'my value'; // In this point the var will be initialized?
```

What happens if I try to use this var outside a thread after the thread has set the value for the var? For example:

```
//at the main thread (application)
  ...
  //Call the thread;
  //thread finishes execution
  //thread is destroyed
  ShowMessage(myThreadVar); // what happens here?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The threadvars for a thread are initialized the first time their thread accesses any one of them. They are set to a default all-bits-zero value, which for strings is the empty string.

Threadvars may or may not be finalized. It depends on how much notice the RTL gets that a thread is terminating. For that reason, it's probably best not to store any dynamically allocated types (strings included) in threadvars. Instead, use an instance variable of a `TThread` object to store thread-specific data.

---

The second part of your question is nonsense. It has you executing code on a thread after the thread has already terminated. There is no such thing as running code "outside a thread." All code runs in threads. Every program has at least one thread.

Each thread has its own copy of a threadvar. No thread can read another thread's copy, so once a thread terminates, all its threadvars are inaccessible.

Your `ShowMessage` call will display the value belonging to the current thread, not the thread that already terminated.

Comment: I think by "outside a thread" he meant "outside the thread in which I assigned a value to it," not, "not in any thread at all."  But you're right, it reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of threadvars.

Comment: If you look at ExitThreadTLS in SysInit.pas, you can see that while the RTL will free the memory backing threadvars is going to be freed, but no attempt is made to finalize it's contents. So any managed variable (string, interface, dynamic array, variant) left in a threadvar will be leaked.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @Thorsten. Note that the function is called when a Delphi *DLL* is detached from a thread. A Delphi *EXE* is not notified.

Comment: It's the only place where the memory backing the threadvars is ever freed. I guess that means that if you keep starting new threads that access a threadvar and then terminate in a delphi exe (as opposed to dll) you should be running out of memory sooner or later.

Comment: *`No thread can read another thread's copy`* -- that's not true, you can get the address of a thread-local variable and access its memory this way, all memory is in the same process-wide address space.

Answer (score 7):

The thread-local storage will be zeroed out (initialized) when the thread is created.  So before you run the line `myThreadVar := 'my value';`, it'll be an empty string.

As for your second question, threadvars are unique to each thread.  When you declare a threadvar, you declare a slot in thread-local storage, and each thread gets a copy of the slot.  You can think of it as kind of like `thread1.myThreadVar`, `thread2.myThreadVar`, `mainThread.myThreadVar`, etc.  So if you set a threadvar in one thread and try to read it in another, you won't read what you set in the other thread; you'll read whatever is assigned to the current thread's version of the threadvar.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to "The thread-local storage will be zeroed out (initialized) when the thread is created" (oficial documentation or oficial source code)? I tried but was not able to found

Answer (score 3):

threadvar means that you have an instance of the variable per thread. There's no such thing as 'outside a thread' - if you're not running inside an explicit thread that you created, you're running on the process' default thread. if you set a threadvar to a value within an explicit thread, that value is invisible to all other threads.